# Addthis sdk for iPhone :passing unwanted url

Tags: iphone, addthis

I have integrated [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) SDK with my application, to share content which is always a simple string. I am using the following code:

```
[AddThisSDK showAddThisButtonInView:self.view
    withFrame:CGRectMake(90, 376, 147, 53)
    forURL:@"www.example.com"
    withTitle:@"code"
    description:@"code i have scanned"];
```

But I actually only need to share the string content, and have no need to pass any URL. When I set `nil` for the value of `forUrl` it doesn't share anything. How can I share a string using this SDK, without having to specify a URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the AddThis sharing to twitter, and to prevent the URL being shown I passed the URL as just http:// as shown below. This may solve your problem.

```
[AddThisSDK shareURL:@"http://" withService:@"twitter" title:@"MyTitle" description:@"MyDescription"];
```